# Object source for UI select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

After selecting an item from the dropdown an error is triggered for every keypress: `origItem.toUpperCase is not a function`, see http://plnkr.co/edit/xxTfWMcK3CuRPuiRldcB?p=preview

My ui select element:

```
<ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="(custom 'new' label)" ng-model="project.tags" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" title="Tags">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Tags">{{$item.name || $item}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="tag in tags | filter:$select.search">
        {{tag.name || tag}}
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

where `tags` is

```
$scope.tags = [
 {
   name: 'foo'
 },
 {
   name: 'bar'
 }
]
```

I didn't find anything about using an object as source for the dropdown - but it seems like I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I check this and this worked for me to resolve the issue. 
1. Add a function to your demo.js

```
$scope.tagTransform = function (newTag) {
var item = {
    name: newTag
 };

 return item;
}
```

2. Second add the function to the tagging tag like so.

```
 tagging="tagTransform"
```

I didn't get the error any more on your plunker when I added this.
Hope this will work.